# Connectivity with C# and Oracle 11g

Tags: .net, oracle

I have to connect c# on .NET with oracle 11g server,while connecting i have to select oracle.dataAccess in .NET but i could not find oracle.dataAccess. My machine is 64 bit windows 10.

Comment: can you provide any code examples of what you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You need to download 64-bit Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) available here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html.

More information here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e23174/InstallODP.htm#ODPNT150.

Comment: Note, ODAC requires also an Oracle Client, it does not work stand-alone (unless you use the ODP.NET Managed Driver `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client`). Visual Studio is 32-bit application. If you like to use the build in connections and wizards you have to install the 32-bit version of ODAC. In case you like to install both 32-bit and 64-bit follow this instruction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104210/badimageformatexception-this-will-occur-when-running-in-64-bit-mode-with-the-32#24120100